# Disable logging for single .Net Core controller endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a simple .Net Core 3.1 web API which is hosted on Azure, and there are excessive health checks to the index route of the application which are flooding the logs with these messages:

```
INFO  2021-12-15 09:48:57,710 [22   ] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics - Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:21021/  
INFO  2021-12-15 09:48:57,714 [22   ] ft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware - Executing endpoint '<RedactedApplicationName>.Web.Host.Controllers.HomeController.Index (<RedactedApplicationName>.Web.Host)'
INFO  2021-12-15 09:48:57,718 [22   ] c.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker - Route matched with {action = "Index", controller = "Home", area = ""}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult Index() on controller <RedactedApplicationName>.Web.Host.Controllers.HomeController (<RedactedApplicationName>.Web.Host).
INFO  2021-12-15 09:48:57,735 [22   ] c.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker - Executing action method <RedactedApplicationName>.Web.Host.Controllers.HomeController.Index (<RedactedApplicationName>.Web.Host) - Validation state: Valid
INFO  2021-12-15 09:48:57,736 [22   ] c.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker - Executed action method <RedactedApplicationName>.Web.Host.Controllers.HomeController.Index (<RedactedApplicationName>.Web.Host), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectResult in 0.0337ms.
INFO  2021-12-15 09:48:57,738 [22   ] vc.Infrastructure.RedirectResultExecutor - Executing RedirectResult, redirecting to /swagger.
INFO  2021-12-15 09:48:57,740 [22   ] c.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker - Executed action <RedactedApplicationName>.Web.Host.Controllers.HomeController.Index (<RedactedApplicationName>.Web.Host) in 20.0366ms
INFO  2021-12-15 09:48:57,741 [22   ] ft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware - Executed endpoint '<RedactedApplicationName>.Web.Host.Controllers.HomeController.Index (<RedactedApplicationName>.Web.Host)'
INFO  2021-12-15 09:48:57,744 [22   ] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics - Request finished in 33.7378ms 302 
INFO  2021-12-15 09:48:57,749 [19   ] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics - Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:21021/swagger/index.html  
INFO  2021-12-15 09:48:57,758 [6    ] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics - Request finished in 9.0414ms 200 text/html;charset=utf-8
```

I would still like to keep Information level logs as I am logging other information I would like to see elsewhere. The endpoint looks like this:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return Redirect("/swagger");
}
```

Is there an annotation I can use to disable logging of this single controller endpoint?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to add the healthcheck middleware and point Azure's health check to that path instead? Redirecting to the swagger page for a health check is a waste of resources imho

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto That sounds like a good idea. I have an Azure Front Door which is sending these health probes to check backend health. Do you have an idea how I can change what endpoint it sends its health probes to? I can't find that option for the Front Door.

Comment: Go to Front Door Designer > Select the backend pool > enable health probes > change Path (right below status)

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use the logLevel config section in your appsetting.json and do something like this:

```
    {
      "Logging": {
      "IncludeScopes": false,
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Trace",
        "System": "Information",
        "Acme.Controllers.IndexController": "None"
       }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I went ahead with the alternate approach by @CamiloTerevinto in the comments of the main post and did not need this. If anyone can test this and confirm that it works I can select it as the awnser.